# How do I get the values of TextCtrl created during a loop in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Say I am creating 6 text control fields using a loop like so:

```
ticker_items = ['bid', 'ask', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']
for item in ticker_items:
    wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value=item, size=(-1, -1))
```

How can I update these after creation?

Answer (score 2):

You can not.
You either must save the object in some way (p.e. a list of objects) or give a different ID to each TextCtrl.

For example:

```
ticker_items = [('bid', 1000), ('ask', 1001),
                ('open', 1002), ('close', 1003),
                ('high', 1004), ('low', 1005)]

for item, id in ticker_items:
    wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, id=id, value=item, size=(-1, -1))
```

Then you can use

```
my_textctrl = self.panel.FindWindowById(id_of_my_ctrl)
```

to get a specific control back

Alternatively, using a list:

```
ticker_items = ['bid', 'ask', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']
self.my_controls = []
for item in ticker_items:
    text_control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value=item, size=(-1, -1))
    self.my_controls.append(text_control)
```

The you retrieve your text number 0 with

```
 my_textctrl = self.my_controls[0]
```

Comment: can I save the object while using a loop? ex. using items as the object name?

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way. You can pass a unique name to the text controls and use it to update them. I've provided a simple example where I update the first couple of controls below:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        ticker_items = ['bid', 'ask', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']
        for item in ticker_items:
            sizer.Add(wx.TextCtrl(self, value=item, size=(-1, -1), name=item) )

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Update")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateTextCtrls)
        sizer.Add(btn)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateTextCtrls(self, event):
        """"""
        txtCtrls = [widget for widget in self.GetChildren() if isinstance(widget, wx.TextCtrl)]
        for ctrl in txtCtrls:
            if ctrl.GetName() == "bid":
                ctrl.SetValue("$100")
            elif ctrl.GetName() == "ask":
                ctrl.SetValue("$500")


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="TextCtrl Tutorial")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The only way to create references to the text controls is to use the setattr method that ikaros45 mentioned.

Comment: IF you know your widgets IDs, you can also use the text control's GetId() method, but I find the GetName one easier.

Answer (score 2):

A really easy way is to store the ctrl's in a dictionary.
I've modified Mike's code to use a dictionary instead see below.

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        ticker_items = ['bid', 'ask', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']
        self.ticker_ctrls = {}
        for item in ticker_items:
            ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=item, size=(-1, -1), name=item)
            sizer.Add(ctrl)
            self.ticker_ctrls[item] = ctrl

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Update")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateTextCtrls)
        sizer.Add(btn)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateTextCtrls(self, event):
        """"""
        self.ticker_ctrls['bid'].SetValue('$100')
        self.ticker_ctrls['ask'].SetValue('$500')


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="TextCtrl Tutorial")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create TextCtrl's like this if you want to later refer to them. Store them.

One way is to add them to the object by using settatr(), and optionally a prefix to give extra information (I used '_text')

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

```
ticker_items = ['bid', 'ask', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']
for item in ticker_items:
    text_control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, value=item, size=(-1, -1))
    setattr(self, '_text_' + item, text_control)
```

And later you can access it and change the value by using for example:

```
self._text_bid.SetValue('Bid v2.0')
```